# Enviar input file en angular por un formulario

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular15

Necesito ayuda. Tengo un formulario que envia varios datos de tipo texto, pero quiero que tambien se envie una imagen que debo cargar mediante un input type="file".

Cuando agregue la funcionalidad del input file, me da el siguiente error cuando abro el modal(add-edit-empleado.component.html) donde se carga el formulario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui dejo el codigo del archivo add-edit-empleado.component.ts donde se encuentra la funcionalidad de enviar los datos del formulario a un api node(que funciona y guarda todo correctamente antes de agregar la imagen):

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { EmpleadoService } from '../services/empleado.service';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { CoreService } from '../core/core.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-edit-empleado',
  templateUrl: './add-edit-empleado.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-edit-empleado.component.css']
})
export class AddEditEmpleadoComponent implements OnInit {

  tipo = 'Empleado';

  empleadoForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder, private empleadoService: EmpleadoService, private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<AddEditEmpleadoComponent>, @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any, private coreService: CoreService) {
    this.empleadoForm = this._fb.group({
      nombre: '',
      apellido: '',
      numDocumento: '',
      telefono: '',
      email: '',
      idCargo: 1,
      idFoto: 0
    })
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.empleadoForm.patchValue(this.data);
  }



  onFormSubmit() {
    if (this.empleadoForm.valid) {

      if (this.data) {

        this.empleadoService.updateEmpleado(this.data.id, this.empleadoForm.value).subscribe({
          next: (val: any) => {
            this.coreService.openSnackBar('Empleado Actualizado', 'OK');
            this.dialogRef.close(true);

          },
          error: (err: any) => {
            console.error(err)
          }
        })


      } else {

        this.empleadoService.addEmpleado(this.empleadoForm.value).subscribe({
          next: (val: any) => {
            this.coreService.openSnackBar('Empleado Agregado', 'OK');
            this.dialogRef.close(true);

          },
          error: (err: any) => {
            console.error(err)
          }
        })

      }


    }
  }


  selectedFile: any = null;

  onFileSelected(event: any): void {
    this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0] ?? null;

  }


}
```

Por ultimo esta el codigo Html donde agregue el input file, si lo borro todo funciona perfectamente.

```
<div mat-dialog-content class="content">

    <div class="row">
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <mat-label>Nombre</mat-label>
            <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Ej. Pedro" formControlName="nombre">
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <mat-label>Apellido</mat-label>
            <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Ej. Perez" formControlName="apellido">
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <mat-label>Número de documento</mat-label>
            <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Ej. 17111888" formControlName="numDocumento">
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <mat-label>Teléfono</mat-label>
            <input matInput type="tel" placeholder="Ej. +58-0424111888" formControlName="telefono">
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
            <input type="email" matInput placeholder="Ej. correo@gmail.com" formControlName="email">
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <button type="button" mat-raised-button (click)="fileInput.click()">Choose File</button>
        <input hidden (change)="onFileSelected($event)" #fileInput type="file" formControlName="idFoto" id="idFoto" name="idFoto">
        <span class="file-name">{{selectedFile?.name}}</span>
    </div>


</div>

<br><br>
<div mat-dialog-actions class="action">

    <button mat-raised-button type="button" [mat-dialog-close]="false">Cancel</button>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit">{{data ? 'Actualizar' : 'Registrar'}}</button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Problema

Muy probablemente el error es este:

```
this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0] ?? null;
```

#### ¿Porque esta mal?

`event.target.file[0]` devuelve un objeto tipo `File`. Un objeto `File` no se permite enviar en un HTTP.
Deberías de utilizar `FormData` o pasar la imagen a base64 para que te permita pasar datos.

#### Ejemplo

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-file-input-with-form-field?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

*No he probado con tu código a ver si esa es la solución*